# applescript textedit character

Tags: applescript, textedit

I have written a script that puts the characters of a document (RTF)from textedit into a list-variable.This is working great but some of the chars I get back are not what I expected.
example would be the ' (single quote) character. was expecting id=39 (ASCII 39) and I get an ID=8217, if I convert that to ASCII (set y_ascii_num to ASCII number x) i get a ASCII 213.

I'm I missing something kind of conversion?

here is the code I use to get the chars:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    open gp_file_in
    set gp_file_in_name to name of document 1
    tell document 1
        set gp_list_char to get characters
        set gp_list_font_char to get font of characters
        set gp_list_size_char to get size of characters 
    end tell

    close document 1
end tell
```

sample test data would be an RTF file created with textedit containing just 4 characters: it’s

Answer (score 0):

ASCII 213 is an angled single quote  (with a slant to it) vs 39, which is a straight single quote (no slant, just vertical)

More details here... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Answer (score 0):

The text in TextEdit and AppleScript and the Mac and the Web is UTF-8, not ASCII. If you deal with it as UTF-8, you won’t get unexpected results.

> the ' (single quote) character

That’s not a single quote, it’s a single prime. It’s a “programmer’s quote” which is why it is featured prominently on the legacy computer keyboard. That character only belongs in computer code. It should never appear in any written text.

> and I get an ID=8217

That is an apostrophe. It’s exactly what you want for a word like “don’t” for example. The “8217” is the UTF-8 code for the apostrophe.

Also keep in mind that when you’re talking to TextEdit, the text is styled text (aka rich text.) And you are dealing with the text as objects, not as literal strings of text. That’s why you can ask TextEdit for the “font” property of a character.

If you just want the text itself, then set the text of the document to a variable:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set theUTF8Text to the text of document 1
end tell
```

I don’t understand why you are trying to convert it to ASCII, but I recommend you try not to do that.